# Is it possible to batch mint 10k NFTs in one transaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

So I'm using ERC1155 and I always get the out of gas error when batch minting at least 200+ NFTs, which means that the gas used for that method exceeds the block gas limit of the blockchain. I'm wondering if this is normal. If so, should I subdivide the 10k into multiple transactions instead..? What else can be a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shouldn't do that much data volume on a single tx.

There are some advanced techniques called rollups that aim to increase the volume of transactions, but they come with their own considerations.

I don't think there is a native workaround to this issue as the whole gas dynamic is to avoid the network being spammed. Writing these "huge" volumes of data is discouraged.

Some "recent" changes have added dynamic limits that adjust block sizes to current EVM chains, but they work progressively. Meaning they adjust depending on demand across several blocks.

Ethereum blockchain was close to 10 TB last time I checked earlier this year.

Comment: I see. So how do people mint (via smart contracts) their 10k NFTs aside from lazy minting (like on OpenSea)?